# vagrant won't start virtual machine - (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I really hit a wall with this problem. I am on windows machine (with admin privileges) and I want to start setup my working environment with vagrant.

Problem is that I am getting error (down bellow) and I can't find any solution... I am using latest virtual box and vagrant version.

Error code:

```
 C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `initialize': The requested address is not valid in its context. - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 7755 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `block in is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `block in catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:19:in `is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:248:in `port_check'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `[]'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `block in handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:257:in `block in with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:98:in `handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:23:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

**EDIT 1: Added Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

require 'yaml'
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/deep_merge.rb"
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/to_bool.rb"
require "#{dir}/puphpet/ruby/puppet.rb"

configValues = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config.yaml")

provider = ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] ? ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] : 'local'
if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-#{provider}.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  custom = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config-custom.yaml")
  configValues.deep_merge!(custom)
end

data = configValues['vagrantfile']

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.8.1'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  eval File.read("#{dir}/puphpet/vagrant/Vagrantfile-#{data['target']}")
end
```

Comment: do you want to foward a port on 7755 ? can you copy your Vagrantfile

Comment: @FrédéricHenri added Vagrant file.

Comment: all your config is in `puphpet/config.yaml` are you forwarding on 7755 ?

Comment: @Frédéric Henri Your answer is correct just a minor typo. It is `host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` not host_id

Comment: @PetrasButkevicius thanks for the note - I correct the answer

Comment: Pathros, download this file below:
https://app.box.com/s/073jwyreskjxdfrlylfvcz1uws0a3o4i Go into your homestead repository, go to the 'scripts' folder and replace the 'homestead.rb' with this one. That will get it to work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the new vagrant 1.9.3 (see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8395)

some were able to [fix](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8395#issuecomment-288379271) with following

> I managed to make the 1.9.3 version working by rewritten all my Vagrantfile(s) and adding the `host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` parameter for each
>   of the "forwarded_port" network configuration.
>
> E.g.:
>   `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 1022, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'ssh'`

For puphpet, you can edit your `/puphpet/vagrant/Vagrantfile-local` search for `forwarded_ports` and replace

```
if !machine['network']['forwarded_port'].nil?
  machine['network']['forwarded_port'].each do |i, port|
    if port['guest'] != '' && port['host'] != ''
      machine_id.vm.network :forwarded_port,
        guest:        port['guest'].to_i,
        host:         port['host'].to_i,
        host_ip:      "127.0.0.1",
        auto_correct: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I spend 3 days to fix this issue, it's very stupid of vagrant, however your solution worked!! thank you, I went through every code in c:/hashicorp and my homestead folder and replaced every 0.0.0.0 with 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yep. It is new version of vagrant that causing problems.. I used 1.9.1 and it's working great. Thank you for your time

Comment: Where exactly do you add that piece of code? I get `Warnings:
* Unknown network type 'forwarded_port' will be ignored.` and anyway I get the same behaviour of `Destroying VM and associated drives...` - `connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 8000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)`. Could you add more details as for where to put the solving code? How many VagrantFiles are there? I can see two in my computer.

Comment: @PedramVdl I see too many files and folders in `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded` :( Which ones did you edit? in which folders??? - This issue is driving me crazy. Arrrgghhhh

Comment: @Pathros, can you link to your Vagrantfile ?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a problem with latest version of Vagrant, 1.9.3.

I downgraded to 1.9.2 and fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you just simply uninstall Vagrant 1.9.3 and then reinstall `1.9.2` without modifying or removing anything else? -> **My own answer**: `Yes`. Simply as that. Just trying to fix everything in version 1.9.3 has been both a big loss of time and a great pain in the ... #$*

Answer (score 1):

## Modify the 'vagrantFile'...

## network forwarded ports net the socket info... IP+port

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8932, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", auto_correct: true

Comment: But where and how exactly? I've read that same answer in several forums ... and I find it unclear and incomplete. Could you please add more details? In that file I could not find that `network forwarded ports net the socket info` ...