# Laravel vagrant up not working - Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have recently had some errors while a part of the Laravel environment or Windows 10 updated, so after a lot of trials and errors I've decided to delete everything and start from scratch. So now I have new VirtualBox, Vagrant, Laravel/Homestead box and Homestead itself.

However, I do get this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> homestead-7: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `initialize': The requested address is not valid in its context. - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 8000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `block in is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `block in catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:19:in `is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:248:in `port_check'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `[]'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `block in handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:257:in `block in with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:98:in `handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/unil/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
```

With about 100 more lines below following. Do you know what seems to be the problem and how to resolve it? I was reading something about RoR, but I didn't manage to resolve it.

Comment: Have you updated your hosts file? Also, I don't think that an IP of `0.0.0.0` works, but that's more a memory than fact-based statement

Comment: Updated to what? I have left it as it was before I reinstalled everything

Comment: Vagrant is complaining that your assigned IP (`0.0.0.0`) is unavailable. Try changing your Homestead.yaml to another IP like `192.168.10.10` and update your hosts file to reflect that IP

Comment: But I don't have that IP anywhere in hosts or yaml

Comment: Weird. Maybe someone else than me can help you..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vagrant won't start virtual machine - (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948757/vagrant-wont-start-virtual-machine-errnoeaddrnotavail)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the new vagrant 1.9.3 (see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8395)

some were able to [fix](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8395#issuecomment-288379271) with following

> I managed to make the 1.9.3 version working by rewritten all my Vagrantfile(s) and adding the `host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` parameter for each
>   of the "forwarded_port" network configuration.
>
> E.g.:
>   `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 1022, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'ssh'`

For Homestead, you can edit the file `Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb`

```
    # Use Default Port Forwarding Unless Overridden
    unless settings.has_key?("default_ports") && settings["default_ports"] == false
        default_ports.each do |guest, host|
            unless settings["ports"].any? { |mapping| mapping["guest"] == guest }
                config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: guest, host: host, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", auto_correct: true
            end
        end
    end

    # Add Custom Ports From Configuration
    if settings.has_key?("ports")
        settings["ports"].each do |port|
            config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: port["guest"], host: port["host"], protocol: port["protocol"], host_ip: "127.0.0.1", auto_correct: true
        end
    end
```

Comment: Oh man...I will give you a gold medal and buy you a truck load of beer. I have downgraded Vagrant to 1.9.0. and all issues which were going on for 3 days are gone. Thank you

Comment: Thanks I'll take the beer :)

Comment: Double confirm downgrading from 1.9.3 to 1.9.0 solved this for me as well. https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.0/ (You want the `.msi` )

Comment: Where exactly do you add that piece of code? I get `Warnings:
* Unknown network type 'forwarded_port' will be ignored.` and anyway I get the same behaviour of `Destroying VM and associated drives...` - `connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 8000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)`. Could you add more details as for where to put the solving code? How many VagrantFiles are there? I can see two in my computer.