# vagrant up - Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL with vagrant version 1.9.3

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I have been trying to install Laravel Homestead and I have been following different tutorials but always when I reach the point where I have to execute `vagrant up` I recive this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> homestead-7: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `initialize': La direcci▒n solicitada no es v▒lida en este contexto. - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 8000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `block in is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `block in catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:32:in `catch'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:19:in `is_port_open?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:248:in `port_check'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `[]'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:121:in `block in handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:257:in `block in with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:253:in `with_forwarded_ports'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:98:in `handle'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.3/lib/vagrant/unil/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
```

The part that says `La direcci▒n solicitada no es v▒lida en este contexto` means `the requested address is not valid in this context` in spanish. The ▒ things are only vowels `ó` and `á`.

This is my `Homestead.yaml` file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\laravel-projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: erpsoftware.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/erpsoftware/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

The directory `C:\laravel-projects` exist, I already added `192.168.10.10   erpsoftware.app` in the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@mail.com"` (of course, replacing 'my@mail.com' with my actual email address).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel vagrant up not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955086/laravel-vagrant-up-not-working)

Comment: Per the duplicate, downgrading Vagrant from 1.9.3 to 1.9.0 solved this for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got multiple issues with Vagrant version 1.9.3
What I did was reinstalling the version 1.9.2 then everything worked fine.

Comment: This is becoming a routine for me nowadays. Update Vagrant, break everything. Rollback.

Repeat.

Answer (score 9):

had the same issue, this is the solution: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8395#issuecomment-288379271

Basically you need to add `host_ip: "127.0.0.1"` to the homestead.rb file in line 90

Comment: And fix is here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/8399, it should be included in v1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is most likely fine. I would try these three things.

First, reboot your machine if you had just installed vagrant.

Second, enter your BIOS (which requires a reboot on most computers) and enable hardware virtualization.

Third, disable hyper V in Windows. This conflicts with vagrant.

Should take care of it for you.