# Hyperledger fabric end to end flow: vagrant up in devenv fails

Tags: vagrant, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, devenv

I'm following the instructions at this link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/e2e_cli/end-to-end.rst

I have set the development environment following instructions here (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv.html)

Now when inside the devenv folder I run 'vagrant up', I get the following:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hyperledger/fabric-baseimage'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hyperledger/fabric-baseimage' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: hyperledger
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-      1.9.3/lib/vagrant/util/is_port_open.rb:21:in `initialize': The requested address is not valid in its context. - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 7050 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

I appreciate some help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel vagrant up not working - Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955086/laravel-vagrant-up-not-working-errnoeaddrnotavail)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with vagrant 1.9.3 which should be fixed in the next release:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/8399

In the meantime you can work around it by specifying in the Vagrantfile the host ip in every port forwarding command:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7050, host: 7050, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" # fabric orderer service

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7051, host: 7051, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" # fabric peer service

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7053, host: 7053, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" # fabric peer event service

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 7054, host: 7054, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" # fabric-ca service

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5984, host: 15984, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" # CouchDB service
```

With this change vagrant up works for me.